# Camerax VideoCapture max duration limit

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, video-capture, android-camerax

I am using Camerax to record a video, one of the requirement is to set the maximum duration to 15 seconds, how to do that?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I do not see anyway to set the maximum duration time, but when I use post delay, VideoCapture starts the video differently from an Android API version to another, it sometimes delay one second and sometimes it does not

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [current sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/VideoCapture.java) I don't see any mentioning of "duration" like the old `setMaxDuration`. So at the moment you'll have to write your own start/stop check.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65109058/5193915 for a possible solution